# UI to initiate content download in AAOS Media App

Tags: android-automotive

I am looking into creating an audio Media App for AAOS.

I would like to allow my users to choose to download specific audio tracks.

I am having a hard time understanding if this is possible.

I found a section in the docs that mentions and encourages implementing offline playback support.
https://developer.android.com/training/cars/media/automotive-os#offline-content

However, it does not mention how this would be acheived.

The part I don't understand is how an button or option would be added to the templated UI that would allow a user to take an action for a specific track or group of tracks such as an album.

The docs also briefly mention the technical aspect of downloading content here, which again leads me to believe it should be possible. I just don't see how a user would initiate the download.
https://developer.android.com/training/cars/media/automotive-os#can_i_use_a_foreground_service

Comment: You could adjust the mediacontroller and add a custom button to download the content.

https://developers.google.com/cars/design/automotive-os/apps/media/interaction-model/playing-media?hl=de

Comment: Specifically you're suggesting adding it to the screen that appears while the content is playing? I like getting suggestions, but the whole point of downloading would be to do so before playing the content.